# 100 Day Countdown

Tags: code-golf, date

It is common to start countdowns 100 days prior to an event, probably because of our base 10 system. Examples of this can be found everywhere:

- 100 days until your birthday
- 100 days until the wedding
- 100 days until the election
- 100 days until our graduation
- 100 days until her due date
- 100 days until football season
- 100 days until you get the Fanatic badge

You get the picture. It seems that the 100th day before an event is second place only to the actual event. So for this challenge, I need to know what the date will be in 100 days, so that I can determine what I should start counting down too.

### Input

No input

### Output

The date 100 days from the current date based on the standard [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (Make sure to account for leap years). Output is flexible as long as the date format is human read-able (eg `2016-10-8`, `10-8-16`, `[ 2016, 10, 8 ]`, `10/8/16 12:00:00 AM`).

### Winning

Code golf: shortest code in bytes

---

#### Examples

100 days from today (Apr 5th, 2017) is Friday, July 14 2017.

```
Current                Future
-------                ------
01/01/2001 +100        04/11/2001
01/01/2004 +100        04/10/2004
01/01/1900 +100        04/11/1900
01/01/2000 +100        04/10/2000

07/04/2017 +100        10/12/2017
10/31/2017 +100        02/08/2018
12/25/2017 +100        04/04/2018

08/29/1941 +100        12/07/1941
06/03/2001 +100        09/11/2001
```

Comment: Can I add the current time to the output?

Comment: @Titus no, just the future date

Comment: Most answers include a date and time now, I think this should be allowed.

Comment: @GB When you output the future date, the format is flexible (could include timestamp) as long as it is human readable. However, current time/date is not acceptable.

Comment: "*Because of our bas 10 system*"?  No, if we counted in binary, we'd likely count down from 100 - except that would take only four days, rather than a hundred...

Comment: `10/8/16` is not human readable, it can be `2010-08-16`, `2016-08-10` or `2016-10-08`. Please avoid this date format

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 this format is perfectly readable for me (in fact, it's pretty much a de-facto standard where I live). It all depends on where you're from.

Comment: @CássioRenan It can not be, because it can be read in 3 different ways. it is not possible to be readable without more informations. (or from where do you know which of this 3 possible formats are used)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 that's not a good point. In fact, `2010-08-16`, `2016-08-10` and `2016-10-08` are also ambiguous. In my case they're much worse: Since there's no date format where I live that starts with a year, I have no way of knowing whether these formats are day/month or month/day. Something being human-readable implies language/convention. In the case of a flexible question such as this one, this means you have to specify the format, along with the date, much like you would do with other types of data. Forbidding a format just because **you** cannot read it is just rude.

Comment: @CássioRenan The problem is not that i can not read this format, the problem is there are 3 different *used* formats which all lock the same. And no one use `YYYY-DD-MM` (it is also the only format which make sense, since it is complete Bigendian and not mixed). To the language language convention, there are english speaking countrys which are `DD/MM/YY` used mostly and other english speaking where `MM/DD/YY` used mostly, so there is no convention which you can count on (so this format is not distinct and therefor can not be readable).

Answer (score 42):

## Excel, 10

```
=NOW()+100
```

#### Demonstration

[image]

Comment: Wow it can be that easy? xD

Comment: Also works in Google Sheets.

Comment: Excel is always good for code golf that involves parsing dates.

Comment: Is there a language pack for excel in which the NOW function is spelled out with just two letters? In that case, you could save 1 byte.

Comment: Yep, Dutch has 'nu()'

Comment: Do `=100+now(` also work? it works in LO-calc

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 the closing bracket is required, at least on Excel 2016.

Comment: Although, per [date part only](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115436/100-day-countdown#comment281752_115436), you'd have to use `=TODAY()+100` or `=TEXT(NOW()+100,"MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: As i already wrote, this format is not readable, not for humans nor for machines.

Answer (score 20):

## Bash, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
date -d100day
```

It turns out the `date` command takes some pretty flexible input for relative timings. You can also do things like `1 year`, `1 week ago`, `yesterday`, etc. It's pretty cool.

-1 byte by realizing that bash does not care about grammar.
-1 byte because the space between `100` and `day` is unnecessary.
-1 byte because I don't need quotes anymore because I don't have a space in the string.
-1 byte by removing the space after `-d` (thanks ASCII-only!)

Comment: New favorite command +1

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Hah, yeah, it's probably one of my favorite commands. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the space after `-d`

Comment: @ASCII-only Oh, okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## PowerShell, 10 bytes

```
(date)+1e2
```

<sup>Thanks to ConnorLSW for the +1e2 trick.</sup>

It appears that doubles (`1e2` is a double) are also added as days.

#### Previous version, 12 bytes:

```
(date)+"100"
```

Apparently you can add strings to dates in PowerShell. The string `"100"` is converted into a 100 days-`TimeSpan`.

Comment: Ok don't ask me why, but even though `(date)+100` doesn't work, `(date)+1e2` does... I guess `1e2` is actually a `double` whereas `100` is a number until it's compiled, i.e. you can't call `100.GetType()` but you can `1e2.GetType()` - that's -2 and brings us to a draw with Excel!

Comment: @ConnorLSW If it help or adds to the confusion `100` is seen as adding 100 ticks where as the string `"100"` is taken as days. Both are valid PS but only one does what we need.

Comment: @Matt `1e6` is still a number and is added as days though?

Comment: That is interesting then. Perhaps there is more going on under the hood where that number reaches over a threshold.... I do not know

Comment: I think it's somehow related to the old [DATE type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69.aspx) which is an 8-byte floating point number with days being represented as whole number increments. I guess that's what Excel is using.

Comment: seems like `(date)+[double]100` also adds as days, so I think @DankoDurbić is totally right, `(date)+[int]100` doesn't, oh Microsoft.

Answer (score 8):

## Mediawiki, 19bytes

```
{{#time:r|+100day}}
```

You may try it with [wikipedia's sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Sandbox&action=edit)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 28 bytes

```php
<?=date(Y_m_d,time()+864e4);
```

human readable version, 35 bytes:

```php
<?=date(Y_m_d,strtotime("100day"));
```

almost readable, 34 bytes:

```php
<?=date(Y_m_d,strtotime(1e2.day));
```

-4 bytes if also printing the time is accepted: replace `Y_m_d` with `r` or `c`.

It´s National Holiday in France in 100 days.

Comment: The underscores made me do "Why underscores, is it a constant? No, a string OH WAIT 'SPACES'!!" Clever.

Comment: @Martijn Turn on `E_NOTICE` and You´ll know: `Y_m_d` is an undefined constant and PHP assumes a string. This works with any valid word (including all function names) apart from [keywords](http://php.net/manual/reserved.keywords), [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php) and case insensitive `true`, `false` and `null`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
p Time.now+864e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@gEJKZm6qXl1@ubWFmkmry/z8A)

Comment: Was going to answer this, nice. But I get different results for `864e4` and `8640000` and I don't quite know why. I blame TIO. EDIT: when you use `p`, the two values produce a different result. But when you use `puts`, they're the same.

Comment: I don't understand, I get the same result with both. Can you post an example? Maybe it depends on the locale?

Comment: `p Time.now+864e4` is around 4 days behind `p Time.now+8640000` on TIO. I tried it multiple times. However, if you use `puts`, this distinction doesn't exist. I don't really know if my locale matters, US East should be pretty normal :P I guess I'll try running it on my own PC when I get home.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only!

Saved 1 byte thanks to @JohanKarlsson

```
new Date(+new Date+864e7)
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML=new Date(+new Date+864e7)
```

Comment: You can use `864e7` instead of `864*10e6`

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `+new Date` instead of `Date.now()`

Comment: This is a snippet. You need to include `console.log`

Answer (score 5):

### SQL (PostgreSQL), 19 Bytes

```sql
SELECT now()+'100d'
```

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, 27 bytes

```
:r!date "+\%F" -d"+100 day"
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@29VpJiSWJKqoKQdo@qmpKCbAmQZGhgopCRWKv3/DwA)

[image]

Edit: Removed unnecessary space char.

Comment: If you're using Linux `date`, the one on this page is `date -d100day`, not sure if it will help though

Comment: I test it with `:r!date +\%F -d100day` this also works (at least on my pc (C)), but is the same as `HyperNeutrino` already use in bash.

Comment: Uh, you can save bytes by just eliminating vim and doing it in bash.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
Z'100+1XO
```

Output format is `15-Jul-2017` (which I find most readable). Change `1XO` to `2XO` to get the format used in the examples, `07/15/17`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@lbmhgoG0Y4f///9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

#### Explanation

```
Z'      % Push current date and time as a serial date number
100+    % Add 100
1XO     % Convert to string with format 'dd-mmm-yyyy'. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

**SQL (Microsoft), <strike>35</strike> 31 bytes**

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(D,100,GETDATE())
```

Comment: You can use `d` instead of `DAY` and remove the spaces inside `DATEADD`.

Comment: Even *I* didn't know you could use `d`. I use `dd` or `day` in practice. I just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>26</s> 21 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @KiranLinsuain!

```
Today+Quantity@"100d"
```

If including the time is permitted, then we can save 2 bytes:

```
Now+Quantity@"100d"
```

Comment: "Now + Quantity["100d"]" cuts it down quite a bit, but may not always work on all versions.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>103</strike> 97 bytes

*Thanks to [raznagul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42502/raznagul) for saving 6 bytes!*

```c#
using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(DateTime.Now.AddDays(100).ToString("d"));}}
```

Full program which reads the current date, adds 100 days and displays the result in `M/d/YYYY` format.

You can change the date format by adding a few more bytes:

```c#
using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(DateTime.Now.AddDays(100).ToString("d-M-yyyy"));}}
```

---

To eliminate boilerplate code - C# isn't exactly known to be very compact - an anonymous function can be used:

## C# lambda, <strike>49</strike> 43 bytes

```c#
()=>DateTime.Now.AddDays(100).ToString("d")
```

Full program:

```c#
using System;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<string> f = 
        ()=>DateTime.Now.AddDays(100).ToString("d");
        
        Console.WriteLine(f());
    }
}
```

Comment: For the full program I think you can write System.DateTime.Now... to avoid "using System;"

Comment: @Taemyr: That would be longer, as he also needs it for `Console.Write`.

Comment: @adrianmp: You can save save 6 bytes by using `.ToString("d")` instead of `.ToShortDateString()`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>77</s>, 61 bytes

```java
()->System.out.print(java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(100))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#DcmtDsIwEABgv6eobAWXobGToCYJ4jiaUdK/7K4ly7LHRpeqT3zkkVnd0MV9yOXpHSkWlE5N7qVCDz3L6uJyfyhcl2r2Nm8sNkAqArmP6A9WBHHBwjUR@gnFQkxfbSD7whNurM/jaMylHcPRfjGdCOlt/w)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't include the boilerplate? (ie 'class A{public static. . .') For Java, I believe at is necessary for a full program. You could do a lambda `()->java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(100)`.

Comment: I had that before editing my answer. It was 94 bytes along with the boilerplate. I new to golfing with java. hence I aint sure  about whether I had to include that!

Comment: Submissions (unless otherwise specified) can be either a full program (runnable by some interpreter without modification) or a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel), 8 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
]5@LaƇ⁺ƈ
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%5D5%40La%C6%87%E2%81%BA%C6%88&input=&run=false)

---

### How it works

```
]5@LaƇ⁺ƈ
]5@La    # The string "]5@La" gets pushed onto the stack which in base 98 represents 8,640,000,000.
     Ƈ   # Pushes an integer that represents the current time where highest resolution is milliseconds.
      ⁺  # Add the time and the string which will be interpreted as 8,640,000,000ms.
       ƈ # Convert the integer to human readable time.
         # Implicitly output to the screen.
```

```html
<div id="noodel" code="]5@LaƇ⁺ƈ" input="" cols="80" rows="2"/>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The character Ƈ is the unicode character U+0187, which is too large to be displayed in a single byte. Same goes for ƈ (U+0188). So while this is 8 characters long, the minimum byte-length is 10.

Comment: @iFreilicht, _Noodel_ uses its own encoding. The editor does everything in _UTF-16_ to work better visually, but gets encoded based off of the _Noodel_ code page before parsing.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>87</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

*saved 2 bytes thanks to [Albert Renshaw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16513/albert-renshaw)*

```
f(){time_t t=time(0)+864e4;puts(ctime(&t));}
```

I realized the output is flexible enough to allow for day of week and time, so there's no need to use `localtime` or the `tm` structure at all.

#### Old answer

```c
f(){time_t t=time(0)+8640000;char b[9];strftime(b,9,"%d-%m-%y",localtime(&t));puts(b);}
```

Based on [Khaled.K's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115517/67236), but instead of messing with the `tm` structure, adds the number of seconds equivalent to 100 days directly to the `time_t` value. It also prints only the date, without time or day of week.

As it should happen on a golfed program, some ugly warnings are generated on compilation.

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/ZFJc7k)

#### Ungolfed:

```c
f(){
    // Current time + 100 days
    time_t t=time(0)+8640000;
    // Buffer for printing formatted time
    char b[9];
    // Print the time in format dd-mm-yy to buffer
    strftime(b,9,"%d-%m-%y",localtime(&t));
    // print buffer
    puts(b);
}
```

Comment: Shave 2 bytes by replacing `8640000` with `864e4`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

```
(d=new Date()).setDate(d.getDate()+100)&&d
```

```js
setInterval(_=>document.body.innerHTML=(d=new Date()).setDate(d.getDate()+100)&&d,1000)
```

Comment: I used your answer as inspiration to mine http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115436/100-day-countdown/115496#115496 ;)

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 29 bytes

```
@Adjust(@Today;0;0;100;0;0;0)
```

Unfortunately `@Adjust` requires the trailing `0's` for the missing `hh:mm:ss`.

If we were allowed to display the time as well then changing `@Today` to `@Now` would save 2 bytes for 27.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
_=>new Date(Date.now()+864e7).toDateString()
```

25  bytes if returning a date with the time is acceptable:

```
_=>Date(Date.now()+864e7)
```

Answer (score 2):

## 30 bytes

**Mysql!**

```sql
select NOW()+INTERVAL 100 DAY;
```

**SQLite**

```sql
SELECT date('now','+100 day');
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>120</s> 113 bytes

```c
#include <time.h>
f(){time_t t=time(0);struct tm*tm=localtime(&t);tm->tm_mday+=100;t=mktime(tm);printf("%s",ctime(&t));}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/O15P4q)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void PrintDatePlus100days()
{
    // obtain current time
    time_t t = time( 0 );

    // convert to datetime struct
    struct tm *tm = localtime( &t );

    // add 100 days
    tm->tm_mday += 100;

    // convert to time_t
    t = mktime( tm );

    // print time in readable format
    puts( ctime( &t ) );
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to account for `#include ...` boilerplate when submitting functions. (Java answers, for example, don't need `import` in that case)

Comment: @CássioRenan in Java you don't need to count the default imports like `java.lang.*`, just like how we don't count `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` in C. But even in java, you need to either consider custom imports or put the path in the class name like `java.util.Date`, and that counts in your score.

Comment: Why using `printf()` would `puts()` not also work?

Answer (score 2):

## F# (53 bytes)

```
printf"%s"(DateTime.Now.AddDays(100.0).ToString("d"))
```

Comment: Don't see a lot of F# answers on here. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 3, 39 bytes

```
print(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:864E4))
```

Comment: I'd argue you don't need the `import foundation;`. Swift runs just on iOS and that is auto imported there.

Comment: There aren't too many Swift answers here yet, so not sure what the consensus is. But I think you have a good point, I'll remove the import :)

Comment: @Albert Swift also runs on Mac OS and Linux. I don't know what that means for whether the import is required, though.

Answer (score 2):

## R (REPL), 14  bytes

```
Sys.Date()+100
```

Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/27USzq).

Comment: This is a snippet. Your code is required to output the result, either as the result of a function, or to STDOUT as a full program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56737/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-armipunk).

Comment: @mbomb007 [REPL answers *are* allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/12012), but they're considered a separate language.

Comment: @Dennis It wasn't listed as REPL before.

Answer (score 2):

**PowerShell, 23**

```
(get-date).adddays(100)
```

This is my first ever try, so please give me constructive feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 63 bytes

```
from datetime import*
print(datetime.now()+timedelta(days=100))
```

Very simple solution really. Because the `datetime.now()` result is the same `type` as the result of `timedelta`, it happily adds the two together.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a function. You could remove the `lambda:` and it would still be a full program.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Yes but `print` would have to be added and that makes it the same number of bytes.

Comment: If you use Python 2, you can remove brackets in `print` to save 1 byte

Comment: the `days=` is optional, that would save 5+1 bytes (python2 `print`'s brackets)

Comment: Golfed down to 57 bytes: `from datetime import*;print datetime.now()+timedelta(100)`

Comment: And he's deleted...:P

Comment: Do you need the `datetime` in `datetime.now()`, if you have already imported `*` from it?

Comment: @SparklePony yes, the `datetime` module includes a `datetime` class. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

Comment: Down to 55 bytes by using `date.today` rather than `datetime.now`: `from datetime import*;print date.today()+timedelta(100)`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 38 Bytes

```
d=new Date;d.setDate(d.getDate()+100);d
```

A little bit shorter than [ASCII-only answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115441/65663).

```js
document.write(eval("d=new Date;d.setDate(d.getDate()+100);d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Golang, 58 bytes

```
import ."time"
func f(){Println(Now().AddDate(0, 0, 100))}
```

Full Program

```
package main

import . "time"
import . "fmt"

func main() {
    Println(Now().AddDate(0, 0, 100))
}
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#K0hMzk5MT1XITczM48rMLcgvKlHQU1BKyy1R@g/jKpVk5qYqcaWV5iUrpGloVgcUZeaV5ORp@OWXa2jqOaakuCSWpGoY6CgAkaGBgaZm7X@wWpCZGpoK1VycQF1ctf8B)

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle, 34 bytes**

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_DATE+100 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 + Pandas 0.19.1, <strike>56</strike> 51 bytes

```
from pandas import*
print Timestamp('now','D')+100
```

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 52 bytes

```
%put%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(date()),100),date9.)
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 21 bytes

```
print(Sys.Date()+100)

"2017-07-16"
```

Comment: you forgot a little zero

Comment: What I mean is that you need a `print` command. You cannot assume a REPL environment. If you run your code [here](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@x9cWaznkliSqqGpbWhg8P8/AA) and it's not printed to Output, then your code isn't a valid solution.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'd like to see some kind of citation that R must work in TIO. I've never seen an R answer link to TIO. I also just ran this code in a Unix terminal and the output was the same. Can I assume the code is allowed to be run in a terminal?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478: Default Program or Function
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7842/8478: but also REPL

Comment: We treat [REPLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) as a separate language. So if your code requires a REPL to execute, you should list it as "R REPL" or something similar. In the same way, `"Hello, World!"` is not a valid "Hello World" program in Python, since it requires `print` in front to actually print to STDOUT in a non-repl environment.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks, and sorry you had to wrangle two of us on this. Now edited.

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, 8 bytes

```
?now+100
```

output:

```
2017-07-16 10:13:19
```

Works in the Immediate Window. Beats Excel by 2 bytes by skipping parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 21 bytes

```
Date(+new Date+864e7)
```

Actually, you don't really need `new` before Date.

Based on [this post.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115496/43214)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = Date(+new Date+864e7);
```

Comment: Uhm, somehow the embracing `Date` function always returns the current date. Is this code correct? Also, you probably meant to write `864e4` if that is supposed to be the number of seconds in 100 days. Maybe the unit is _milliseconds_, I don’t know.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 20 bytes

```
print Date.today+100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QlJlXouCSWJKqV5KfklipbWhg8P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
wVs2h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@29oYBBWbJTx/7@BoT4QGRkYGAIA) (doesn't use literal because I can't figure out how to embed it)

```
w      -  get 100 in 2 bytes
  Vs2h - Repeat ^ times
   s2  -   increment the day part
     h -  strip the time part
```

Hexdump:

```
77 84 56 73 32 68
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 43 bytes

```
BEGIN{print strftime("%F",systime()+864e4)}
```

Could save a few bytes if run using some input... maybe... using something like:

```
{$0=strftime("%F",systime()+864e4)}1
```

and running the code like:

```
awk '{$0=strftime("%F",systime()+864e4)}1'<<<1
```

But then we have to account for the bytes used to do that.  So I'll stick with simplicity :)

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 18 bytes

```
dateadd(d,100,now)
```

Answer (score 1):

## k6 and [q](https://kx.com/), 8 bytes

```
.z.d+100
```

Apparently, `.z.d` returns the current date, and the default units when adding to dates are days.

[image: Running the command above in q and k6.]

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/d9345826-45da-4a7f-9e17-baf0516c4d5e#sidebar=compute), 19 bytes

```
DatePlus[Today,100]
```

Kinda self-explanatory but let's explain.

**DatePlus** (From Wolfram Language Reference)

> **DatePlus**[date,{n,"unit"}]
>   gives the date n units after date.
>
> Possible offset units are "Year", "Quarter", "Month", "Week", "Day",
>   "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Weekday", "Weekend", Monday through
>   Sunday, "EndOfMonth", and "BusinessDay".
>  Offsets can also be specified
>   using the Quantity framework. 
> {y,m,d} is taken to be equivalent to
>   {y,m,d,0,0,0} etc. 
> DatePlus[date,offset] gives results in the same
>   general format as date. 
> When date is a list, the result has the same
>   length as date, possibly extended to include the smallest unit in
>   offset. » 
> When date is a string, the result is in the form specified
>   by $DateStringFormat.

**Today** (From Wolfram Language Reference)

> **Today**
>
>   gives a DateObject representing the current day.

So basically, it just adds 100 days to the current date.
See screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab/Octave, 16 bytes

```
datestr(now+100)
```

Pretty much self-explanatory and (a bit) boring, but could not be missing!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ð864e7+Kj
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0Dg2NGU3K0tq)

My first Japt answer!

A port of the existing JS answer.

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS, 96 bytes

```
require('http').createServer(function(q,s){s.end(':'+new Date(Date.now()+(864e7)))}).listen(8e3)
```

My first codegolf attempt ever, but I can't find anything to make it shorter.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Just because NodeJS is a server framework, you don't have to make a server to display the output. Something as simple as `console.log` would suffice for outputting the result :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien true, but I thought it may worth an entry to show, how NodeJS can utilize the same result *with it's intended purpose*. However, you may argue, whether http server is the sole purpose of the framework, so I admit it may have been unnecessary.

Comment: Even so, you can shorten it with an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 16 Bytes

This program requires an HP‑41CX or an HP‑41C/CV with a time module plugged in.
After energizing the clock’s electronics, the clock is set to January 1, 1900, 0:00 a. m, so set the clock first.

```
01♦LBL⸆T           5 Bytes  global label requires 4 + (length of string) Bytes
02 DATE            2 Bytes  obtain current date in MM.DDYYYY or DD.MMYYYY format
   NULL            1 Byte   invisible Null byte before numbers
03 100             3 Bytes  push 100 on to the stack (Y ≔ date; X ≔ 100)
04 DATE+           2 Bytes  add 100 days (X) to today’s date (Y) and yield date
05 FIX 6           2 Bytes  ensure _all_ digits of the date are visible
06 RTN             1 Byte   `RTN` does not affect local label search
```

The `X` register (the top of the stack) now contains the date in `MM.DDYYYY` format (or `DD.MMYYYY` should you have changed that by invoking the `DMY` command).

**Limitations**:
The result of the `DATE+` and other time‑related calculation operations can be “any date from October 15, 1582 (the beginning of the Gregorian calendar) through September 10, 4320” (quoted from the HP‑41CX Owner’s Manual Vol. 2).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 53 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
print("\(Date()+864e4)".prefix(10))
```